# Upload image with dropzone and CodeIgniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload, dropzone.js

I want to combine my form and [DropzoneJS](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) in **CodeIgniter**.

In CodeIgniter when I want to upload multiple images I use foreach and use library upload and save into database.

How to combine dropzone so it will be like input type file and can submit with other value in 1 form?